# Can we use Admob in Android Webview App?

Tags: android, webview, admob

I just want to know is it legal and approve to use Admob in Android Webview App ?

I have a technology blog and I am planning to make a Webview Android App and publish on playstore with Admob ads, can i use admob in my ads ?

Comment: adsense would probably fit the role better.

Comment: Do you mean Ads in the android webview? or do you have ads in your blog?

Comment: I am talking about using admob with Android Webview.

Answer (score 0):

You use the admob ads there is no problem on webview. but you avoid overlapp content and also with adsense ads do not serve on the app.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion it violates Google's Policy. they say you have to use **Admob** with your native Android App. if your **WebView** is a part of your Android App then you can use **Admob** as well.